# Python class self variable as default when no argument given error

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, error-handling, self

I am writing a `class` in `Python3` and want a method to take a default self variable when no explicit value is given. For some reason this doesn't seem to work.

For example, the following code would produce a `NameError: name 'self' is not defined` error for the 5th line.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def func(self, b=self.a):
        pass
```

Is there a way around this if I want to make my function behave in the manner I specified?

Comment: I see it is the same as the duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you want.

If `func` is invoked without a parameter then `b` would be set to the value of `self.a`.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def func(self, b=None):
        if not b:
            b = self.a
        pass
```